# Kotlin sequence "skip" first N entries

Tags: kotlin, sequences

How can I "skip" the first N entries of a kotlin sequence/list?

I am looking for the kotlin equivalent of [C# LINQ "skip"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 128, accepted):

You are probably looking for the ["drop" function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/drop.html) known for example from [from lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#drop):

```kotlin
val seq = 1..10

seq.drop(5)
> [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Note that in your example `seq` is not a `Sequence`, but an `IntRange`  which is `Iterable`. Nevertheless `drop` extension function is available both for `Sequence` and `Iterable`.